# Is Exception Handling about transferring control?

Tags: exception

Is Exception Handling about transferring control from the called routine to the calling routine or is it about throwing messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct answer to this question is "yes" -- it allows you to send a message back to the caller that says "I've encountered an error/exceptional condition; you may now do something about it".

Comment: I dont think it happens in every language. What if there is an exception which is not thrown.

Comment: If an exception is not thrown, it must have been handled somewhere.

Comment: I think it should be left to the calling routine as to what should be done about it as the called routine should be reusable for different scenarios.

Comment: That is not always true as the routine being called may be using other routines that the calling function doesn't know about.  If one of those produces and exception, the called routine may want to handle it to reduce coupling.  Now that being said, the problem may be bad input data or something where an appropriate response may be to pass that info back up to the calling routine.

Answer (score 1):

Exception handling is about handling exceptions.

It's useful if you want your program to crash gracefully, or If your program does many things and you don't want it to grind to a halt because one non-critical operation failed.

You generally want to log or display your exceptions in some way, so you at least have a stack trace when your program fails.

Comment: What I felt about Exception Handling is this . We have to transfer the control to the Calling Program/Routine rather than having the Called Program/Routine handle it on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Exception handling is a generic term which is pretty self explanatory. It describes any code used to handle unusual circumstances AKA "exceptions" that may occur during operation.

As for your transferring control or throwing messages question that depends entirely on the language. Not all languages allow throwing of exceptions so that part just depends on which technologies you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Exception Handling is about capturing errors that produce exceptions and reacting appropriately.

Throwing an exception is a technique that allows both information about an exception and responsibility for handling it back to the calling function.  It is saying something happened in the function that could not be recovered from while still completing the expected operations of the function.

An exception may be handled within a function by throwing an exception, so they can also be combined.

Comment: But there has to be a difference between an "Error" and an "Exception" ?

Comment: One should indeed be careful with terms.  I have modified my answer a bit to make it clearly applied to exceptions.  Thanks.